# Problems with missing value in csv reader in python

Tags: python, csv

I have a problem with csv reader. All values are empty after first call.
I have a code like listed below.
After I use values `open_time_min`, `open_time_max`, I can't them use more than one time.
After second call for value, it is empty.
Can anybody tell me what I'm do wrong?

```
csv_data = csv.reader(open(FILE_PATH +".csv"))
open_time_min = min(csv_data)[0]

csv_data = csv.reader(open(FILE_PATH +".csv"))
open_time_max = max(csv_data)[0]
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the minimum and maximum of column 0? What type of data is it... integers? If you post a small sample CSV file, it would help to answer.

Comment: When you say you can't use `open_data_min` more than one time... I don't see you using it _any_ times. Post a simple example of what fails.

Comment: If you read the documentation for `csv.reader()` there is helpfully an example of how to use it. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?highlight=csv.reader#csv.reader

Comment: You aren't showing us the failing code, the data that causes the fail, or what you'd like the code to do. I think this question should be closed until its complete enough to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`csv.reader`<sup>[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?highlight=csv.reader#csv.reader)</sup> creates an iterator over the file handle that gives you one row per iteration. Reading through the file once exhausts the file iterator, so you can't read through it again unless you `seek()` the file handle to the start.

You shouldn't do it this way though. Instead, if you have enough memory, you should read all the data into a variable *once*, and then perform your operations on it.

```
with open(FILE_PATH +".csv") as file_handle:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(file_handle)
    csv_data = [row for row in csv_reader]
    # or csv_data = list(csv_reader)
```

Note that each item in `csv_data` is a list of strings that represents a single row of your csv file. If you don't want it to be a list of strings, you will have to convert it as you read it. For example, if the file is all numeric, you can do:

```
with open(FILE_PATH +".csv") as file_handle:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(file_handle)
    header = next(csv_reader)
    csv_data = [[float(elem) for elem in row] for row in csv_reader]
```

Now, `csv_data` is a list of lists, and you can operate on it any number of times.

---

Depending on your application, it might make more sense to convert this list of lists to a numpy array (if it is completely numeric) or read it as a dataframe using `pandas`.

For example, consider a CSV like so:

```
open_time,data0,data1
0000,10,3
0010,30,2
1500,32,12
2000,12,1
```

Using numpy:

```
import numpy as np

# Convert csv_data list-of-lists to a matrix
csv_matrix = np.array(csv_data[1:], dtype=float64) # Slicing to get rid of header
# Or, read it directly from the file
csv_matrix = np.loadtxt(FILE_PATH + ".csv", skiprows=1) # Skip header
```

This creates a matrix that looks like:

```
array([[0.0e+00, 1.0e+01, 3.0e+00],
       [1.0e+01, 3.0e+01, 2.0e+00],
       [1.5e+03, 3.2e+01, 1.2e+01],
       [2.0e+03, 1.2e+01, 1.0e+00]])
```

And you can get the max and min of the first column like so:

```
open_time_min = csv_matrix[:, 0].min() # Result: 0
open_time_max = csv_matrix[:, 0].max() # Result: 2000
```

Using Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(FILE_PATH + ".csv")
```

creates a dataframe like this:

```
   open_time  data0  data1
0          0     10      3
1         10     30      2
2       1500     32     12
3       2000     12      1
```

You can use the `open_time` column from this:

```
open_time_min = df["open_time"].min() # Result: 0
open_time_max = df["open_time"].max() # Result: 2000
```

Comment: Read the documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?highlight=csv.reader#csv.reader

Comment: @balmy I don't understand what you're getting at. Is something wrong with my answer?

Comment: Only that you’re missing a link to the documentation; pointing particularly novice programmers at the documentation gives them a reason and method for getting to it and potentially learning a lot of useful information. But evn for non-novices having that link can be really useful particularly given the batteries-included scope of Python that can be invaluable.

Comment: @balmy good point. I added the link to my answer. Thanks!